# Return multiple values by reference

Tags: php, function, reference, return

I am trying to return multiple variables in a function to another php page.

I looked at other sources but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function byRef($value1, &$value2, &$value3){

    global $value1, $value2, $value3;

    string.$value1 = "Hello";
    string.$value2 = "World";
    string.$value3 = " ";

    string.$value3 .= $value1 . $value2 ;

}

byRef($value1, $value2, $value3);

echo $value3;
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: For starters, "`string.`" is invalid...?!

Comment: What's the `string.$varname` syntax? And I get `HelloWorld`, what's the problem?

Comment: And what is the global good for?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ... they might be better alternatives

Comment: @sachleen hmmmm I am running 5.4.7 perhaps its something to do with that?

Comment: @dbf It was from a previous post... declare the variables as global?

Comment: @Baba I am trying to retrieve the menu_order I can get it to return a single value but I want to be able to return Parent menu order / Child menu order and append it to the menu... issue is wp_list_pages() specific to each page... so the appending value for all menu changes...

Comment: What function are you using to get the single value ??? the code above definitely would not work

Comment: `return $value3;` then call the function byRef();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use global, it imports the variables that are not in the function.

Don't use that string. something either. I don't know what it is or if it exists, but don't use it.

```
<?php

$value1 = 'not hello';

function byRef($value1, &$value2, &$value3){

    $value1 = "Hello";
    $value2 = "World";
    $value3 = " ";

    $value3 .= $value1 . $value2 ;

}

byRef($value1, $value2, $value3);

echo $value3;
```